# How to get date picker dialog result in a text view and how to pop up radio buttons on android dialog button click

Tags: android, radio-button, datepickerdialog

I am new to java and have learnt basic java only and a fresher. I am working on company's app in which I am stuck in two places. It's a leave application app. so here is my two Que.

1. I have taken Two date picker dialogs from which I get two dates = date, date 1. Now i have subtracted these two dates and i am getting its result in a text view but on onClick event. I simply want that as soon as click on second date picker dialog it shows the result in text view without the need of clicking on text view.
2. And like if someone wants to take one day leave and in both date picker dialogs the date is same like 04/03/2017 in both the date picker dialogs so as soon as he click on the second date picker dialog the two radio buttons should pop and we can select full day and half day from it and submit the data.

so here are my two queries please help.

I am posting my code here.

Xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_leave"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.nilesh.sackinfostaff.Leave"
android:background="@drawable/body">


<TextView
    android:text="LEAVE APPLICATION"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textColor="#0000FF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<Spinner
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView22"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/date2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/date2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText8"
    android:text="To Date"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView23"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

<TextView
    android:hint="Leave Balance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView27"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:text="From date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView23"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date2"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#d4d4d4"
    android:hint="To Date"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#FF0000"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/date"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/date"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />




<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#d4d4d4"
    android:hint="From Date"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:backgroundTint="#27ae60"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView23"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView23"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView23"/>


<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioleave"
        android:layout_width="268dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/no_of_days"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">



<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_full"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Full day"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioleave"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/date" />


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_Half"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Half Day"

        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioleave"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/no_of_days"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/no_of_days" />

</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:text="Type Of Leaves"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView22"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView34"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/no_of_days"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/no_of_days" />


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText7"
    android:hint="Enter Your Reason Here"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioleave"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/date"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/date"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="Forward To"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView33"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText7"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText7"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView33"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Leave Balance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView26"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView22"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView22"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView22"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

<TextView
    android:hint="Result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/no_of_days"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="true"/>

<TextView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView33"
    android:id="@+id/textView35"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/date2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/date2" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

My java code

```
public class Leave extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView date;
private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
TextView date2;
//TextView setDay;
private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog2;
TextView no_of_days;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_leave);

    date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    date2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date2);
    //setDay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.setDay);
    no_of_days = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_of_days);

    // initiate the date picker and a button
    date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    // perform click event on edit text
    date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // calender class's instance and get current date , month and year from calender
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
            // date picker dialog
            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Leave.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                            date.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    // initiate the date picker and a button
    date2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date2);
    // perform click event on edit text
    date2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // calender class's instance and get current date , month and year from calender
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
            // date picker dialog
            datePickerDialog2 = new DatePickerDialog(Leave.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                            date2.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog2.show();

        }
    });

    no_of_days.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
            String date01 = date.getText().toString();
            String date02 = date2.getText().toString();
            try {
                Date d = format.parse(date01);
                Date d1 = format.parse(date02);
                getDifferenceDays(d, d1);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.leave_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}


 public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements 
 AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


    SpinnerActivity() throws ParseException {
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
}



private void setupRadios() {
    RadioButton radio_full = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_full);
    RadioButton radio_Half = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_Half);
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioleave);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            int buttonId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            switch (buttonId) {
                case R.id.radio_full:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected Full Day Leave", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.radio_Half:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected Half Day Leave", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}

public void getDifferenceDays(Date d1, Date d2) {
    int daysdiff = 0;
    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + 1;
    daysdiff = (int) diffDays;
    no_of_days.setText(Integer.toString(daysdiff));
    System.out.println("day count=>" + daysdiff);
}
```

}